# How to create a column with buttons in Smart Templates

Tags: sapui5

I want to create a column which provides a button for each row and when I click on the button I want a javascript file to be called. This should be done in the smart templates.[image: Like this]

Answer (score 0):

Embed a responsive table inside your smart table, add the column and link it to the p13n catalogue. [Example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.smarttable.mtableCustom/preview)

Comment: I am using smart templates in UI5. So where shall I write the code for the view and controller?